# View only unread messages in macOS Messages

Tags: messages

Is there any way to view only unread messages in Messages.app in macOS?  The behavior I'd like is basically the same behavior as a Mail.app smart mailbox showing on unread emails.  The volume of texts I get for work makes scrolling down to find unread texts a less-than-ideal solution.

If I'm not mistaken, there's no way to do this directly in Messages.app, so a third-party or other solution would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

So I finally found one way to do this in macOS Monterey 12.6. Right click on the Messages.app icon in the dock, and you'll get a list of all conversations containing unread messages between **New Message** at the top and the **Options** section below. Once you click on one of them, it takes you to the conversation and marks it as read.